# how to distro hop without dual booting

Tags: linux-mint, distributions

I'm on Linux mint 19.3, and I want to know how to Distro hop, without dual booting.
It's fine if it's like a factory reset where I lose all my data.
I have a USB with 4 GB its the same one I used to switch from Windows to Linux.

Comment: Create a 'multisystem'  usb key, and add ISOs at wich ti try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download an ISO and use an appropriate tool to create a live boot on your USB stick. Something like `unetbootin` should do the trick. Assuming the ISO is smaller than your stick.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a website `distrotest.net` that spins up a cloud-bsaed clean install of any of dozens of linux distributions of your choosing. You can evaluate any of those distributions from within your browser. Their website claims, "There are no restrictions for the operating system: You can use all functions of the system, Uninstall and install software, test installed programs and even delete or format the hard disk or system files..."